# Can't make item 1 of <<script>> into type string in Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm getting this error after exporting my script as an application. When running the script in script editor it works fine. But when running the application I get his error

> Can't make item 1 of <> into type string

here is the code I have for it.

```
set deptList to {"basketball", "football", "golf", "compliance"}

(choose from list deptList)
if result is not false then
    set dept_name to item 1 as string
else
    display dialog "Operation Cancelled"
    error number -128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
set dept_name to text of result
```

Applescript knows it's a string (or text) already, so we just need to tell it to set the variable `dept_name` to the `text` of the `result`.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set deptList to {"basketball", "football", "golf", "compliance"}

    (choose from list deptList)
    if result is not false then
        set dept_name to text of result
    else
        display dialog "Operation Cancelled"
        error number -128
    end if
    display dialog dept_name
end tell
```

Comment: "Applescript knows it's a string (or text) already" -- That's incorrect: `choose from list` returns a list of text values. Saying `text of <list>` merely returns another list containing every item of the first list that's a text value. (Perhaps you were thinking of `<list> as text`, which coerces the list of text to a text value.) The clearest correct solution is to assign the result of `choose from list` to a variable (`set userChoice to choose from list deptList`) so you can work with it at leisure, then use `set dept_name to item 1 of userChoice` to extract the text value from the list.

Comment: @foo, I think you're misunderstanding the context in which I'm referring to `"string"`. I'm referring to the `"result"`, not the `"list"`.

Comment: No, I understand fine. `choose from list` always returns `false` or a list of text. That value gets temporarily bound to the `result` variable (itself a language mis-feature best avoided). Your `text of result` reference then retrieves this list and gets all of its text items as a new list, e.g. `text of {"basketball"} -> {"basketball"}`. So the value assigned to `dept_name` is is still a list of text. It's not obvious to you because the `display dialog` command automatically coerces it to text before displaying it, but replace it with `return dept_name` and you'll see.

Comment: As myself, DJ, and foo point out, "text of result" is incorrect. Just because AppleScript is forgiving of mistakes doesn't mean future readers should use the code above as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Choose from list has nothing to do with the Finder. Also, there is no text of result. There is a text returned of result but that is "present only if ‘default answer’ was supplied" with a dialog. Lastly, you should avoid using "result" altogether and assign the response to a variable.

```
set deptList to {"basketball", "football", "golf", "compliance"}
set dept_name to choose from list deptList with title "Insert your Title" with prompt "Insert your prompt" without multiple selections allowed

if dept_name is false then
    error number -128
else
    set dept_name to first item of dept_name
end if
```

Here is an example where using text returned of result would be applicable:

```
display dialog "Enter text" default answer "My text" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
return the result
```

Comment: You're way off here with your assumptions. Review the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_lexical_conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH214-SW19)

Comment: — "The result of a statement is the value generated, if any, when the statement is executed. For example, executing the statement 3 + 4 results in the value 7. The result of the statement set myText to "keyboard" is the text object "keyboard". A result can be of any class. AppleScript stores the result in the globally available property result, described in “AppleScript Constant.”

Comment: In addition to that you're wrong about `choose from list` as well. "choose from list (verb)Choose one or more items from a list (from the User Interaction suite, defined in StandardAdditions.osax)". You need to remember this is Applescript, which is meant to be forgiving in most circumstances — there's more than one way to get the same results, whether you think it's incorrect or not.

Comment: I suggest you read Matt Neuburg's "The Definitive Guide". "What’s more, using result is, I would argue, a downright bad idea. To use result is to be dependent upon AppleScript’s rules about what a statement’s result is." "Also, result is volatile. It changes after the execution of every expression. If you get into the bad habit of not capturing values when they are generated, because you intend to pick them up later using result, you are just asking for trouble."

Comment: choose from list is from the User Interaction suite, defined in StandardAdditions.osax and should not be included in a Finder block. Again, you are wrong about text of result. If you believe you are correct, show me where...

Comment: If you have an example of the result execution I'd like to see it in action. Maybe Finder doesn't have any bearing on the User Interaction Menu, but why does it matter? It can be removed or left there - does it change anything? probably not.

Comment: See my edit for an example.  In your answer, result and text of result will return the same value. Try it yourself.

Comment: If you can show me that the AppleScript I posted fails to do what it supposed to then I will gladly accept your explanation as valid. And what does it matter that result and "text of result" are the same value? They're supposed be - that's what my first comment stated.

Comment: Back to the unnecessary tell application block. Both parties are right here, or wrong. You can have user interaction in the context of another application, a very beautiful feature. However many books, tutorials and snippets seems to put this often in a tell application "Finder" block. That part is not necessary and if not needed it is bad programming because user interaction is in the wrong context. The result is that the code is working but it's clumsy both in code and use. But when you write a script for the Finder, it's very normal to have user interaction in the Finder too.

Comment: The result constant can be any type of object. For the result of an choose list it's either a list or an boolean value false. text of result will be in this case create a new list with all items of the list of class text. Adayzdone is right here, the code works but that doesn't mean it's good programming. When looking at the Joshua's code, he wants to get the first item of the result, while you are giving him all the results. But Joshua just forgot to tell from what object he wants the first object. item 1 of result would have fixed his problem.